# AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config:109: Option expected in windows-8 64 bit

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm using windows-8 64 bit machine. I installed VisualSVN server 2.5.2 in another machine(windows-7 32 bit), created a repository(MyRepos) and enabled subversion authentication. But I'm not able to connect the repository by using my windows 8 64 bit machine. It showing following error message while trying to get "svn list cmd",

```
     svn-win32-1.7.5\bin>svn.exe list https://10.3.6.98/svn/MyRepos
     svn: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config:109: Option expected.
```

But there is no such subversion folder inside the Roaming folder. Roaming folder is empty.
I'm able to connect this repository from another window 7 32 bit machine.

I also installed VisualSVN server in my windows 8 64 bit machine itself and created a repository and enabled the subversion authentication, but not able to connect from my machine itself.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

This is a client-side issue and looks like it's caused by some misconfiguration. As the first step I'd check whether you get the same error when you run `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svn.exe list https://10.3.6.98/svn/MyRepos`. This way you run svn.exe that comes bundled with VisualSVN Server, not the one at .../svn-win32-1.7.5/.

The `%APPDATA%` (`/AppData/Roaming`) directory can't be completely empty BTW. The error message indicates that the config file `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` exists but there is a syntax error on the line 109. You can get the error if a line unexpectedly starts with a whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this answer solved the problem. The config file mentioned on line 109, after an svn update, someone added 1 single white space to the beginning of 3 consecutive arguments. Removing the white spaces stopped the error.